# .htaccess rewrite cant find what i want

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite some urls with .htaccess, because I don't like `domain.com/link.php/string=1234`, it's way too long.

So I want to rewrite it to `domain.com/1234` using .htaccess. But that `1234` string is just a placeholder.
Hence, it could also be `4321` and then it have to be rewritten to `domain.com/4321`.
I know that this is possible with .htaccess but I'm not an expert with that and I didn't find  a good, specific tutorial on Google.

I'm stuck and I can't find anything, so I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Do you mean `?string=1234` instead `/string`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code in the .htaccess file in your web root (usually /var/www):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rewrite the URL and pass it to link.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /link.php/string=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite all URLs to include "/link.php/string=".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /link.php/string=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

But im searching for something so domain.com/1234 wil redirect to domain.com/link.php/?string=1234
Someone?

Comment: Please note that this is not a forum thread. If you have other stuff to say edit your question or comment.

Comment: My answer and anubhava's answer will both do that.